# how to find number of element present in array in google-script (marco excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array,

```
    a="12-13-14" or "12-13"
    arr = Split(a, "-")
    b=Len(a)
```

it shows error. All I Need is b=3 or 2.

Comment: Did not get you

Comment: `b=Ubound(arr)`

Comment: I would love if you mention it in answer it may help lot of guy(begginer) like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the find the upper limit of an array. To find the upper limit, use `Ubound` and to find the lower limit you can use `LBound`

**Example**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Arr(10)

    Debug.Print UBound(Arr) '~~> Returns 10.
    Debug.Print LBound(Arr) '~~> Returns 0.
End Sub
```

You can read more about it in [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ubound-function) and [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/lbound-function)

So what you want is `b=Ubound(arr)`